# NetSuite script to copy line field in another

Tags: javascript, netsuite

Is it possible to create a custom script for copy a custom line field to another standard line field after I select the first field.

For example. I have a custom line field in a item receipt (this field is releated to custom record, in the name (name for record) contains the loction name), after I select that field, is it possible to copy in a location line standard field?

We will be attentive and thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Client Script and its `fieldChanged` event handler for this. Whenever your custom field changes, you can copy the new value over to the native field using `setCurrentSublistValue()`.

Be aware that setting the second field on change of the first will fire `fieldChanged` again, so you need to be sure you're guarding against an infinite loop or preventing the loop altogether with the `ignoreFieldChanged` option of `setCurrentSublistValue()`.

Learn more about the various events fired by records here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=coLkgeuTFFM and about working with sublists here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n05OiKYDxhI